# How can I calculate % completed with a column that is either blank, has a date or the word "pending"?

Tags: excel

I have data like below.  Each row has either a blank (don't count), a date (completed) or the word Pending (not started).  Is there a formula I can use on the bottom rows that will check all the rows above and tell me the % that have been completed? So for the case of Angelica who has completed 11 of 12 in total I would like to see:  92%

[image]

Note the first column to count here is E4 and the last E17.  I would like to get the percentage in E18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
=(1-(COUNTIF(A3:A17,"Pending")/COUNTA(A3:A17)))*100
```

Which gets:

[image]

Comment: Does your code take into account the fact there are rows with no entry also?  What I am not sure of is if the second count you have only does a count if that row is not empty?

Comment: counta counts the nonblank cells, so if you put in a value like 'pending' or a date, the calculation will change. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTA`/`COUNTIF`:

```
=1-COUNTIF(A3:A17,"Pending")/COUNTA(A3:A17)
```

[image]

Comment: Does your code take into account the fact there are rows with no entry also?  What I am not sure of is if the second count you have only does a count if that row is not empty?